# Can I set constants in awk that occur only on the first line?

Tags: bash, unix, awk, gawk

I have a file where all lines are the same but the first line has a set of constants I would like to use for all the other fields.

**File.txt** (Tab Delimitted)

> A  B  C 1  2  3  4
>
> D  E  F
>
> G  H  I

I Want the outcome to be along the lines of

**ExpectedOutcome.txt**

> 1  2A  B 3  C  4
>
> 1  2D  E 3  F  4
>
> 1  2G  H 3  I  4

The current code I have will only process the first line correctly then exits

**ActualOutcome.txt**

> 1 2A B 3 C 4

**Code**

```
#!/bin/sh
Begin{FS="\t";OFS="\t"}
{
      if(NR=1){
           FirstConstant=$4;
           SecondConstant=$5;
           ThirdConstant=$6;
           FourthConstant=$7;
       }
       if($1){
            Combo=SecondConstant $1;
        }
        print FirstConstant, Combo, $2, ThirdConstant, $3, FourthConstant;
  }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With `awk`:

```
# space separatered output
$ awk 'NR==1{a=$4;b=$5;c=$6;d=$7}{print a,b$1,$2,c,$3,d}' file
1 2A B 3 C 4
1 2D E 3 F 4
1 2G H 3 I 4

# tab separatered output
$ awk 'NR==1{a=$4;b=$5;c=$6;d=$7}{print a,b$1,$2,c,$3,d}' OFS='\t' file
1   2A  B   3   C   4
1   2D  E   3   F   4
1   2G  H   3   I   4
```